# ASP.NET MVC + Kendo: Binding to Hidden Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, model-binding

I have a derived class with a property hiding the property in the parent class, like so:

```
public class Parent
{
    public SomeObject Field { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public new SomeOtherObject Field{ get; set; } 
}
```

Essentially, I'm binding a Kendo grid to an `IEnumerable<Child>` object and would like one of the columns to display the value of a property in `Child.Field`, i.e. `Child.Field.SubField`. However, when the code runs, it appears to be trying to bind to the super class' version of `Field`, which is null, hence throwing a `NullReferenceException`.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there someway I can force MVC to bind to the child's version of the field? I was unable to find any documentation on either ASP.NET or Kendo about how they treat hidden properties.

Comment: Are you sure that the grid widget in the view is configured to use the correct type - Child? Can you post your view and controller code?

Comment: @Orilux, unfortunately, the code is proprietary, so I can't share it, but yes, I'm confident it is configured to use the child object (if you need, I can put together some dummy code to show you how the view and controller are structured). The view existed previously and worked fine when it was bound to the property from the base. I didn't see this problem until I hid the property and used a property of the same name as a different type. It may help to note that the property on the child object, `SomeOtherObject` is a derived class of `SomeObject`.